# Gson: parameter get serialised even though it has @Expose(serialize = false)

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm writing an SDK for a JSON API and I'm running into a seemingly weird problem. The API is quite strict in it's POST data validation and it does not allow certain parameters to be present when updating resources, like an `id`. For this reason, I added `@Expose(serialize = false)` the ID field of my resource class. It seems however, that it still serializes this field, causing the request to be rejected. The resource class roughly is as follows:

```
public class Organisation extends BaseObject
{
    public static final Gson PRETTY_PRINT_JSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    private String parentId;

    public String toJson()
    {
        return PRETTY_PRINT_JSON.toJson(this);
    }
}
```

My unit tests create an instance of `Organisation` via the API, saves the newly created instance to the test class as a class parameter and calls an update method that will test the update implementation of the SDK by updating the new resource. This is where it goes wrong. Even though the `toJson()` method is called on the new `Organisation` to serialise it to JSON for the update request, the `_id` field remains present, causing the API to decline the update. The test code is as follows. Notice the comments in the code.

```
@Test
public void testCreateUpdateAndDeleteOrganisation() throws RequestException
{
    Organisation organisation = new Organisation();
    organisation.setParentId(this.ORGANISATION_ID);
    organisation.setName("Java Test Organisation");

    Organisation newOrganisation = this.MySDK.organisation.create(organisation);
    this.testOrganisation(newOrganisation);
    this.newOrganisation = newOrganisation;

    this.testUpdateOrganisation();
}

public void testUpdateOrganisation() throws RequestException
{
    // I tried setting ID to null, but that doesn't work either
    // even though I've set Gson to not serialise null values
    this.newOrganisation.setId(null);
    this.newOrganisation.setName(this.newName);

    // For debugging
    System.out.println(this.newOrganisation.toJson());

    Organisation updatedOrganisation = this.MySDK.organisation.update(this.newOrganisation.getId(), this.newOrganisation);

    this.testOrganisation(updatedOrganisation);
    assertEquals(newOrganisation.getName(), this.newName);

    this.testDeleteOrganisation();
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that the instance already has/had a value for ID, but that shouldn't matter if I explicity tell it not to serialise it right?

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: At `this.MySDK.organisation.update(this.newOrganisation.getId(), this.newOrganisation);`, that does not edit the organisation instance. The given ID is merely added to the URL that the SDK will POST to (`POST /organisation/{id}`)

Comment: Try making it `transient` instead

Comment: @cricket_007 I did that before but then it's ignored on deserialization. I used `@Expose` to have more control over it

Comment: Seen this? https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-ignore-fields-with-expose

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I know it. What do you propose me to change from that tutorial?  Quote: "An alternative to using \@Expose is to declare a field as transient. A transient field will not be (de)serialized either. However, you don't have full control like you do with \@Expose. You cannot deactivate one direction, transient will always completely turn off the conversion for that property."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to @peitek for pointing out that `@Expose` is ignored unless `.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` is added to the `GsonBuilder()`. However, I choose not to go with this route as it would require me to add `@Expose` to every single parameter of my model classes just to ignore one field on serialisation. Instead I wrote a `ExclusionStrategy` that checks for the presence of a custom `SkipSerialisation` annotation on the parameter. I implemented these as follows:

The full `GsonBuilder` with the strategy:

```
public static final Gson PRETTY_PRINT_JSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f)
            {
                return f.getAnnotation(SkipSerialisation.class) != null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz)
            {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();
```

And the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SkipSerialisation
{
}
```

Now I can just do

```
@SkipSerialisation
@SerializedName("_id")
private String id;
```

and it works!

Comment: `f.getAnnotation(SkipSerialisation.class) != null` can be replaced with `f.isAnnotationPresent(SkipSerialisation.class)`.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Even better! I'll use that

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv In which version of Gson is that? I don't have that method.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry! I was confused with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#isAnnotationPresent(java.lang.Class) . Shame on me!

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Ah! Not a problem. You're a Java genius otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

As you mentioned in your comments, `@Expose` should be the better choice over `transient` here. It's important to note that the **default Gson instance does not regard the `@Expose` annotation**! It'll simply ignore it, no matter what you set as option.

If you want to activate the `@Expose` options, you need to customize Gson. Based on your code above, change it to:

```
public static final Gson PRETTY_PRINT_JSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        .create();
```

Your `@Expose(serialize = false)` should be active and excluded during serialization.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I thought `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` did exactly what the name suggested, but that `Expose` would still work if I wanted to do something specific. That does mean that I have to add Expose to every field in all my models right?

Comment: Yes, agreed. That function name is not ideal. And yes, you'll need to add at least an `@Expose()` to every field in the relevant models.

Comment: Thank you. After looking the docs, it clearly says: _If we created Gson with new Gson(), and execute the toJson() and fromJson() methods then @Expose will not have any effect on serialization and deserialization. (...)_ https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-exclude-or-ignore-fields/

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add here that you could use Expose in the desired way like this:

```
builder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            Expose annotation = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            if(annotation != null)
                return !annotation.serialize();
            else
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            Expose annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            if(annotation != null)
                return !annotation.serialize();
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
    builder.addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            Expose annotation = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            if(annotation != null)
                return !annotation.deserialize();
            else
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            Expose annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            if(annotation != null)
                return !annotation.deserialize();
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    GsonBuilder()
        /**   WARN : the function result is :
         *         just Serialization the field and class which with @Expose
         * */
        /*.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()*/



          /** addXxxxxxxxxExclusionStrategy Function is the best selection
                 define yourself exclusion rule
          */
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
            object : ExclusionStrategy {
                override fun shouldSkipField(fieldAttr: FieldAttributes?): Boolean {
                    return fieldAttr?.getAnnotation(Expose::class.java)?.serialize == false
                }

                override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
                    return clazz?.getAnnotation(Expose::class.java)?.serialize == false
                }
            })
        .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(object : ExclusionStrategy {

            override fun shouldSkipField(fieldAttr: FieldAttributes?): Boolean {
                return fieldAttr?.getAnnotation(Expose::class.java)?.deserialize == false
            }

            override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
                return clazz?.getAnnotation(Expose::class.java)?.deserialize == false
            }
        })
        .create()
```